# Why does my <body> content get overlapped by the content "included" from an external file?

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I was following [this tutorial](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=11&video=17028) to learn about the `include` and `include_once` functions in `PHP`.
The following files work just fine:
**index.php:-**

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
echo 'variable';
```

**header.php:-**

```
<h1>My Page's Header</h1>
```

But when I try to include the following `.php` file into my `index.php`, it does not produce the desired result. **The header rather overlaps and thus completely hides the 'variable'**

**What I want is that after I include the header from an external file, My page should start underneath the header. The header included from external file should not be considered included in my page, so none of the elements are overlapped or such. How can I achieve that?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .top-bar {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background: #000029;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .logo {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top-bar">

            <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" >

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

---

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';



?>

<div id="parent_div" > 

    <script>
        function getHeaderHeight() {
            return document.getElementById("top-bar").height(); //top-bar is in header.php
        }
        document.getElementById("parent_div").style.padding-top="getHeaderHeight()";
    </script>

    <h1>Heading</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: try including header.php by absolute URL

Comment: @RonakPatel That did not help but I'd like to know why did you think that was supposed to help? It was not a problem of the path, if it would be a path problem, there would be an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what the big code sample at the end is supposed to indicate. When you view source on the output is it correct? Is this a CSS (display) problem or a PHP (output) problem?

Comment: @jacobwalker0814 Please read the description before the "big code sample", it is the file which when included in `index.php`, it no longer produces the desired effect... Yes the output is correct... I am not sure, so I posted the question!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your header is set to `position: fixed;`. It is taken out of the document flow and will follow you as you scroll arround.

When you want it to not stick to the client top, change your css to this:

```
.top-bar {
    position: relative;
    background: #000029;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

If you like your header to be fixed, you may also set a padding to the body of the document, that equals the height of your header.

Here you see your current problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3W8/

Solution 1: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3W8/1/

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 3000px;
    /*new:*/
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.top-bar
{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Solution two: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3W8/2/

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 3000px;
}
.top-bar
{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The question now is that seeing the header file I posted, how can I get the height of the top-bar which I would add to my div as the padding? The height in both of your examples is set to 30px, but in my code, it's not set to a hardcoded pixel value

Comment: Very good question. Sadly there is no simple anawer for that. But when you search on SO about fixed header height you will find a solution

Comment: Hi, I found out that it is possible by jQuery function height(). So I did what I am posting in the question, but it did not help at all. The header included from the external source and the the content of this page are still overlapping.